# Discrete logarithm algorithm MATHEMATICA

Tags: cryptography, wolfram-mathematica, polynomials

Can someone help please?

I'm trying to solve the discrete logarithm problem (g^x≡h*mod(p)) in a Galois Field. I'm looking for a tool to figure out if my algorithm is working. I guess that Mathematica can do it but I'm not familiar with this software. I found the method "MultiplicativeOrder" which solves this problem if I'm working with integers for example : g=3, p=113, h=57 [MultiplicativeOrder](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiplicativeOrder.html)[3,113,57] results in an output of x=100 which I expected.

But I'm working with polynomials (g,p and h are polynomials) so this method will not help me...

I also found this method : [PolynomialMod](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialMod.html) but I'm not sure if this solve the discrete logarithm problem.

Thank you for your help

Comment: try mathematica.stackexchange.com. You really should give example input polynomials and expected outout

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on mathematica.stackexchange.com